gRPC reflection example in c++ / Windows
I installed bazelisk (bazel --version is 7.1.0) and cloned the current gRPC repo (1.62.2). I want to build the reflection example for cpp on Windows. In the examples\cpp\reflection folder I run
bazel run :reflection_server

it builds and does a lot of things, but finally fails with
ERROR: C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/socgw7ey/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/BUILD.bazel:23:11: Compiling src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.cc [for tool] failed: (Exit 2): cl.exe failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target @@com_google_protobuf//src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp:csharp) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.cc(11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.h': No such file or directory
ERROR: C:/users/admin/_bazel_admin/socgw7ey/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/BUILD.bazel:132:11: Compiling src/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc [for tool] failed: (Exit 2): cl.exe failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target @@com_google_protobuf//src/google/protobuf/compiler:command_line_interface) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h': No such file or directory
Target //examples/cpp/reflection:reflection_server failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: C:/atlas/grpc/examples/cpp/reflection/BUILD:17:10 Compiling examples/cpp/reflection/reflection_server.cc failed: (Exit 2): cl.exe failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target @@com_google_protobuf//src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp:csharp) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)

the most interesting part to me is "Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.h': No such file or directory". What's going on with csharp?
when I run the same command repeatedly, the error alternates between the above and just the one for google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h.
